# Ensure requests are Ajax only in JAX-RS / Jersey

Tags: ajax, jersey, jax-rs

Is there anyway in JAX-RS, Jersey to ensure a request is Ajax only?

The goal here is to ensure that a number of endpoints are only accessed as AJAX calls and not as a Web URL in a browser?

Reason is the request may contain query parameters that are PHI and we don't want them going into Browser history.

Comment: Can you explain why? Do you mean accept only POST and not GET ? Or with specific header(s)?

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP request triggered by an AJAX call is not different from any other HTTP request from the POV of the server. Even more, if your web application makes an AJAX request, you can use the tools your browser provides to inspect, copy and manipulate the request. Modern browsers provide the option to copy the exact request as a `curl` command that can be executed in the shell of your OS. To the server there is not difference between the original made by the browser and the copied request.

There is no way to do what you want to do.